# Enum use in a C program

Tags: c, enums

For the code:

```
void main()
{
   enum a{a,b ,MAX};
   printf("%d",MAX);
}
```

Why is the output `2` in this case?

Comment: What do you know about enums? There are hundreds or even thousands of C texts that explain them sufficiently to answer this extremely simple question. Is this homework? An interview question?

Comment: Previously you asked "Please let me know how does << and >> operator works in C? " Are you going to ask a question for every bit of C syntax? Note that your questions are getting negative votes and being closed as not real questions. Go read a book or a tutorial or take a programming course before asking these sorts of questions, which are not appropriate for a Q&A site.

Comment: Please put more thought and time into your questions in the future. At the least, questions should contain several sentences, ending with an actual question. Kindly, don't just 'drop code' here for others to figure out. If you really need help with problems, it's worth your time to put in additional effort.

Comment: @Jim Is it is simple questn dn why shld nt u xplain it???

Comment: If u hv any prb dn dnt cmmnt here..if hn no rit to insult ny persn

Comment: @Moumita Das y shld nt u du yr ohn wrk n stp abusing SO?

Comment: @Moumita Das No one here insulted you. But you are now trolling.  Stop it.

Comment: for ur kind information m nt absund dis site.ok..Everyone is nt talent like u.got it

Comment: @Moumita Das "m nt absund dis site" I have no idea what that says. Please write in complete sentences, or at least complete words. "Everyone is nt talent like u" -- The issue isn't "talent", it's the way you are communicating and the sorts of questions you are asking.

Answer (score 5):

The output is 2 because MAX is 2. The enum is used to create names for constants. In C, if you don't explicitly specify a value for an item in the enum, the value is 0 if it's the first item, or one greater than the previous for subsequent items. So, in this case: `a` is 0, `b` is 1, and `MAX` is 2.

FYI: an enum is like a bunch of `#define`s, except the values do not need to be constants. See [the entry on enumerations in the GNU C manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/gnu-c-manual/gnu-c-manual.html#Enumerations), assuming you use GNU C.

In terms of the values assigned to the identifiers, the C99 standard has this to say (section `6.7.2.2/3`):

> The identifiers in an enumerator list are declared as constants that have type int and may appear wherever such are permitted. An enumerator with `=` defines its enumeration constant as the value of the constant expression. If the first enumerator has no `=`, the value of its enumeration constant is 0. Each subsequent enumerator with no `=` defines its enumeration constant as the value of the constant expression obtained by adding 1 to the value of the previous enumeration constant. The use of enumerators with `=` may produce enumeration constants with values that duplicate other values in the same enumeration.

Comment: @Harry because MAX is 2 according to the enum

Comment: it's probably more correct to say that the default for the first is 0, the default for all others is one more than the previous - this would explain things like `enum a {x,y=7,z}` being `0,7,8`.